# systemctl enable works but systemctl --user enable does not

Tags: service, systemd, systemctl, ipfs

I have a DO droplet running Ubuntu 16.04.1x64 and I'm trying to run [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/docs/install/) as a systemd service. I've gone ahead and created a user "connor" and installed IPFS following the instructions [here](https://ipfs.io/docs/install/). I'm storing the service as "ipfs.service" in ~/.config/systemd/user/ipfs.service which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=IPFS Daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ipfs daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill ipfs
Restart=always
User=Connor

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

What's odd is that if I run **systemctl --user start ipfs** it starts up just fine. However, running **systemctl --user daemon-reload** and then
**systemctl --user enable ipfs** I get the error:

> Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

However, if I run systemctl enable **/home/connor/.config/systemd/user/ipfs.service -f** it runs just fine. I can reboot and run IPFS commands just fine. I'd like to run it as a user though, and would also like to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you executing the commands with `connor` user?  notice that using sudo to execute commands might change the user to `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check that you are executing the commands with `connor` user, you may run `whoami` to see the user executing the command. (running the command with sudo changes the user to `root`)

In addition, I see that the user in the service file is capitalized (Connor instead of connor), this could bring other problems, and it is not needed, as a simple configuration like the [one proposed by Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPFS) works for user daemons.

Please find bellow the configuration I used for my ipfs daemon, (without User= and with a different Restart=, since Restart=always gave me problems while starting the daemon):

```
[Unit]
Description=IPFS daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ipfs daemon
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```